# Run command at gdb breakpoint, neither c or cont works

Tags: linux, gdb, kernel

I'm trying to run a command that prints information when a breakpoint is hit:

```
(gdb) break XXX
(gdb) command
> printf "xx=%p, yy=%d\n", p1, p2
> end
```

It seems to work, I see lots of outputs.

But suddenly it stopped working, and I saw a line says:

`---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---`

Am I missing something? I don't need to see anything on the screen now, 'cause I already enabled logging in gdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But suddenly it stopped working, and I saw a line says:

Try run `set pagination off` or `set height unlimited` before you run your program. This is from doc:

> If you specify a height of either unlimited or zero lines, GDB does
>   not pause during output no matter how long the output is. This is
>   useful if output is to a file or to an editor buffer. ... Turning
>   pagination off is the alternative to set height unlimited.

References:

- http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html