# How to disable "Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit" in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I want to automatise *gdb*, and waiting for the user input is undesirable. How to disable the message `"Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit"` in *gdb*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command at gdb breakpoint, neither c or cont works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588615/run-command-at-gdb-breakpoint-neither-c-or-cont-works) (feel free to reverse close-vote if you think it's appropriate. However, I think that the other answer is older, and it provides one more option (`set height unlimited`), and some docs quote.)

Comment: The two questions end up having the same answer, but the reasons for asking were different. I don't think we should mark this question as a duplicate. It is the first page if you Google `Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit`, which I think it's quite useful.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Disable pagination: `set pagination off`

Source: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html

Comment: Is it possible to do this at startup, using only the CLI (no `~/.gdbinit`)? `gdb -ex 'set pagination off'` does not seem to work, it only applies once the first command promt is reached. If a warning like `File ... auto-loading has been declined`, I still get `--Type <RET> for more`.

Comment: Try `-iex` instead of `-ex`. `--batch` may be more appropriate if you're trying to automate gdb.

Comment: --batch works indeed, -iex 'set pagination off' doesn't (but definitely --batch is more appropriate)

Comment: [`-batch` documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options) (notice *single* dash).

Comment: I put this in my `~/.gdbinit`, and I can confirm it's off after I start a `gdb` session and run `show pagination`. But... I still get the pagination on start up of gdb when my gdb terminal window is too short.